# How to decorate a function while adding variables in Python

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying to construct a decorator in Python where I add a variable at the decoration stage. I know how to write a decorator where I simply run a function on the results of another function, but I'm having trouble with the syntax of adding an additional variable. Essentially, I want to take this dot product function:

```
def dot(x,y):
    temp1=[]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        temp1.append(float(x[i])*y[i])
    tempdot=sum(temp1)
    return tempdot
```

and subtract the value 'b' from the result, all in one larger function given parameters x,y,b

Am I trying to misuse the decoration functionality in this case? Thanks.

Comment: I may be missing something, but is there any reason you couldn't call `dot` (defined elsewhere) from inside your larger function and then subtract the value `b` from the result, such as `result = dot(x, y) - b`?

Comment: I can, but is there a way to do it with decoration? I'm trying to learn the functionality as much as I am actually solve the immediate problem.

Comment: You can do it, but this doesn't really appear to be the right use of a decorator.  Unless "subtract b" is a functionality you want to apply to many functions in a standard way, and you want all `dot` calls to do it, you really want a separate function that calls `dot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import functools

def subtracter(b):
    def wrapped(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def decorated_func(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs) - b
        return decorated_func
    return wrapped
```

Then use it as

```
@subtracter(b=5)
def dot(x,y):
    temp1=[]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        temp1.append(float(x[i])*y[i])
    tempdot=sum(temp1)
    return tempdot
```

By the way your dot function can be shorted with a generator expression like so:

```
def dot(x, y):
    return sum(float(x)*y for x, y in zip(x, y))
```